# Create a new sheet and coping data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code which will create a new worksheet on selecting A2 which works fine, but what I am also trying to do is to also copy the data in the row 2 and copy this across into the new sheet. Along with this if I click on A3 to create another worksheet, I want to copy the data in row 3 across to that sheet, and so on.

Any ideas??

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange()

Dim cTab As Integer
cTab = ActiveCell.Row - 1


    If Selection.Count = 1 Then

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A201")) Is Nothing Then

            Dim WS1 As Worksheet
            On Error Resume Next
            Set WS1 = Worksheets(cTab & ".")

            If WS1 Is Nothing Then

                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                ActiveCell = cTab & "."
                    Sheets("Template").Visible = True
                Sheets("Template").Select
                Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Name = cTab & "."
                'Sheets("Template").Visible = False
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True

                Else

                Sheets(cTab & ".").Select

            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your code to something like the below, which should copy the rows as you described.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cTab As Integer
    Dim BaseSht As Worksheet
    Dim NewSht As Worksheet

    Set BaseSht = ActiveSheet

    cTab = ActiveCell.Row - 1

    If Selection.Count = 1 Then

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A201")) Is Nothing Then

            Dim WS1 As Worksheet
            On Error Resume Next
            Set WS1 = Worksheets(cTab & ".")

            If WS1 Is Nothing Then

                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                ActiveCell = cTab & "."
                Sheets("Template").Visible = True

                Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Name = cTab & "."
                Set NewSht = ActiveSheet

                BaseSht.Select

                'Copy row to new sheet
                BaseSht.Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":" & BaseSht.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address).Copy NewSht.Range("A" & cTab + 1)

                'Sheets("Template").Visible = False
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True

                Else

                Sheets(cTab & ".").Select

            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, works a treat. Just changed NewSht.Range("A" & cTab + 1) to NewSht.Range("A1") to have it copied to where i needed it.